# A very weak reference (cannot be turned into shared)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-references

I'd like to know if there is any smart pointer type concept that implements the "very weak reference" idea.

This would be basically a `weak_ptr` but that cannot be turned into a `shared_ptr`, basically, when you have `very_weak_refs` out-there, you are sure that the strong-ref count can never go up.

This would allow better "strong ownership" of memory by managers, and delivering very weak references in the wild would still allow clients to access the data by using good old raw pointer through a `.lock_get()` function or equivalent... (name designed to mirror what you would have doing `.lock().get()` usually).

You don't have the same security on data, because your object may be destroyed while you use it, but if your environment is controlled enough so that you know that the manager's cannot clean its data while you are processing, you're still good to use raw-pointers locally after having checked against `null_ptr` after `lock_get()`.

Do any of you wished for similar thing, more info/intelligence/thoughts on that ?
thanks.

rationale : the motivation behind is that `weak_ptr` has the "security flaw" of being turnable to shared and therefore, after distributing weak references in the wild, you basically did the same than distributing shared ones because anybody can keep very long lived shared refs on your data effectively preventing correct cleaning by the entities that were suppsed to be strong (the manager).

This is solved by very-weak-refs, when you distribute that kind of objects in your manager's public interface, you are sure that when you delete your last shared ref, your data is deleted.

For me, the whole concept of weak references works only with well behaved clients; who understands that they should promotes their weak refs into shareds for only small amounts of time.

Comment: What? So when there are badly-behaved clients you want to change the behaviour from what you get with `weak_ptr` (resources are not released until the badly-behaved client releases its `shared_ptr`) to undefined (manager releases the resources and the badly-behaved client is left using a dangling pointer). And when there are no badly-behaved clients, nothing changes. Doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: So basically you want a standard implementation of dangling pointers?

Comment: What you ask for is sound - you mean `lock_get` would return `nullptr` for expired `very_wek_ptr`s, right? I don't think you really need it though - if clients are keeping `shared_ptr`s around for longer than they need to, they're Doing It Wrong (TM). There are many (many!) other ways they can do things wrong, in C++ or in any language, but we don't try to engineer ways to prevent them - you have to assume clients will have some amount of programming skill at some point.

Comment: But an ordinary weak_ptr already returns nullptr if it's expired. The important detail is that returning a `shared_ptr` on success is safe, and something else that doesn't keep the refcount alive isn't. It's asking for a pointer to an object that is concurrently deleted while you use it.

Comment: @BenHymers: that is right yes. And I repeat it, my environment (game engine) allows me to know that Run() function (where I am) running at a certain level will not execute while memory management is running (another level). You all fail to see the point of my rationale, I explained the part of adding an Invariant to my memory management. This invariant is "I AM the owner". Not "I may be.. you know.. but he.. if somebody else wants to be.. whatever.". This is unacceptable. You are all too afraid of dangling pointers like if it was the boogieman. Debuggers do exist for Bjarne's sake !

Comment: @Damon Absolutely - I assumed the OP knew that what he was asking for couldn't be threadsafe.

Comment: @v.oddou Say that again after working late every day for a week trying to find a memory scribble in a release build which turns out to be caused by a dangling pointer! Some advice: use whatever safety features are available to you, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` included!

Comment: @BenHymers: Even in absence of threads, this is not safe. Imagine the smart pointer holding the refcount going out of scope, and you use your very weak reference afterwards. The object is being deleted while you are still using it. Or imagine calling a function that decrements the refcount, or a thousand other things. That is the reason _why_ `weak_ptr` makes you lock the object before use and that is _why_ it returns a `shared_ptr` on success (and `nullptr` otherwise). It's safe. You know that the object you use is valid and will remain valid while you use it.

Comment: @Damon I think we're imagining different use cases for this. I thought that the pointed-to object would only be accessed immediately after the call to `lock_get` (normally in the same expression, even), which in the absence of threads would be fine. Of course if the raw pointer is kept for longer than this, it becomes dangerous, and possible for the pointed-to object to be destroyed (it would be exactly the same as using `get` on a `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @BenHymers : yes the intended scenario is the same than in your last phrase. As I said, I am not looking for guaranteed safety. Just a way to forcefully guide clients to use the pointer for as little time as possible. I have debugged horrors in my days, compiler bugs even sometimes. Yes, the one that everybody says doesn't exist. A dangling pointer is tough, but you have valgrind, you have application verifier, you have the CRT in debug mode and many helpers. One week is really extreme, you were either inexperienced, out of luck, or on a poor platform.

Comment: Xbox 360 (PPC), optimised code, multithreading, DLLs, and the problem being exposed in an incredibly terse implementation of facets and locales. Not at all fun. But I'd still rather just use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` properly rather than have to use tools to find problems, no matter how good the tools are; safe practices should be the default approach. That's just my opinion, and I don't think we're going to agree, so that's my last word on it (promise!).

Comment: @BenHymers: you're wrong ! No I'm just kidding :) Why would I disagree with your views ? I too use safe practices when I wish for something to work with the most guarantee I can put in it. Being an engineer is about chosing tradeoffs. Sometimes I trade safety, its very rare though. Also completely out of topic, but you may want to check : [link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/650567-unique-ptr-shared-ptr-weak-ptr-best-practices/#entry5112722) . This is my colleague, he recently encountered many perf issues due to reference counters being allocated. If you make games, careful of overuse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is impossible with the traditional interface of smart pointers.

The issue is one of lifetime. A `weak_ptr` cannot be use to access the object directly, because it does not guarantee that said object will live long enough: the object might be pulled right from under your feet.

Example:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(4));
    std::weak_ptr<int> wp(sp);

    if (not wp.expired()) {
        sp.reset();
        std::cout << *wp << "\n"; // Access WP ? But there is nothing there!
    }
}
```

Thus, for better or worse, there is *no other choice* than recovering a shared pointer from the weak pointer any time you actually need to access the object *without controlling the duration of this access*.

---

This last point, however, is our clue. A simple idea being to write a well-behaved client of `weak_ptr` yourself and change the way it allows the external world to access the data. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class very_weak_ptr {
public:
    very_weak_ptr() {}

    explicit very_weak_ptr(std::weak_ptr<T> wp): _wp(wp) {}

    template <typename F>
    void apply(F&& f) {
        std::shared_ptr<T> sp = _wp.lock();
        f(sp.get());
    }

private:
    std::weak_ptr<T> _wp;
}; // class very_weak_ptr
```

*Note: there is one remaining flaw, `enable_shared_from_this` allows to recover a `std::shared_ptr<T>` from the very instance of `T`; you can add a compile time check on `T` to prevent usage of this class with such objects.*

Comment: You know thanks to the second part this is a pretty good answer. You bring a very interesting concept here, the `apply` function, which shelters the scope of shared-ification, lovely idea. However the first part just repeats what I said in the first line of the 4th paragraph in my question. And that is wrong because shared_ptr are not 100% safe (no correctness guarantee under threading, raw pointer leakage through get() or `&(*)`, construction of another ref count class if not using shared_from_this...). You've got to be smart usng smart ptrs. They don't barricade well.

Comment: What I mean to say, is that my "impossible" like you qualify it, is the same level of "impossible" that is already in use with shared_ptr. So I don't accept that as an introduction of an answer. You could remove the whole entire first part and I'd accept it though :). in the meantime you have my upvote.

Comment: @v.oddou: You are right, this answer was written "au fil de l'eau" and it showed; I've rewritten part of the text to make it more coherent with itself. As you correctly identified, the key point is controlling the scope in which ownership is shared; though to make it totally safe you would probably need to rewrite a `shared_ptr` implementation *without* the `enable_shared_from_this` backdoor.

Comment: @v.oddou Actually C++11 `shared_ptr` is guaranteed thread-safe. And calling it "Not 100% safe" is true of anything you can write to replace it.

Comment: @BenHymers: `shared_ptr` is thread-safe, but indeed it is up to the developer to secure the shared resource (fortunately).

Comment: @MatthieuM : even with rewriting shared_ptr this wouldn't be safe. Through `apply` you can call a method that returns `this` and you've got your flaw again. But I said it many times, nothing is 100% safe, life is not safe, meteorites can fall, meningitis can strike, cars can crash. Dread is a hindrance, http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/dont-be-afraid-of-imperfection/

Comment: @BenHymers: in my knowledge, shared_ptr is not thread safe. http://cppwisdom.quora.com/shared_ptr-is-almost-thread-safe It has 2 reference counts to maintain which cannot be done atomically.

Comment: @v.oddou: I never said access to the underlying object could be made thread-safe; regarding `shared_ptr` itself, it did seem we were not considering the same cases, my focus (and Ben's probably) was that different instances accessing the same underlying "count + object" could be manipulated independently without further synchronization, I agree that a single instance should not be shared between threads nilly-willy.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: well this is off topic :) My opinion is that even in the case when 2 threads are manipulating different instances, say (1) holds a `weak` and the other thread (2), a `shared` ; then access to the ref counter (shared, both smart ptrs point to that same ref counter) will cause a hazard in the case of (2) calling `release()` (RW access) when in the same time (1) will call `lock()` the `cmp/xchg` OP on the strong count will return 0 so (2) will enter the `if` branch that calls `delete` on the pointee. But if (1) already checked the strong count, it is now delivering a `shared`. boom

Comment: @v.oddou: I would hope that the implementers took care of this kind of detail, and consider any implementation that does not support this usecase to be non-conforming.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: the boost doc was very blury and misleading, it said that it fully supported conclurrent reads but not mingled read/writes (the case I described above). The new standard (havn't read it yet) apparently stipulates a stronger guarantee (from what I read in the MSDN). But if it is true, I believe it to be a mistake. check the gcc code: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a01034_source.html clearly there are 2 consecutive swaps in `__shared_ptr(__weak_ptr)` that are not atomics and they break exactly the case I mentioned.

Comment: they also mention "_It is not possible to avoid spurious access violations_", and we can see they do their best to use barriers to make changes visible to other threads. But that is the only guarantee we get on safety. I believe the flaw I mentioned exist, and will cause a double call to delete on a dangling pointer. And this, in purely standard usage of the smart pointers only, without even doing any access to the pointee.

Comment: @v.oddou Sorry to sound so harsh, but I'm afraid your opinion doesn't matter - what matters is the standard, and that says that `shared_ptr` is thread-safe! The source you linked is old - a more up-to-date implementation should be thread-safe. The blog post is just mentioning what Matthieu and I have said, which is that the pointed-to object still needs to be guarded against concurrent access, which includes being deleted by the owning `shared_ptr` - the same as with *anything* being accessed by multiple threads. `shared_ptr` just guarantees that its internal state will remain consistent.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is functionally equivalent to, starting with a `std::shared_ptr<>`:

- initially creating a `std::weakptr<>` thereto + `.get()-`ting a raw pointer,
- before use of the raw pointer, checking the `weak_ptr<>` hasn't `.expired()`.

> Do any of you wished for similar thing, more info/intelligence/thoughts on that ? thanks.

No... if you need to check the `weak_ptr<>.expired()` anyway, you might as well get a valid `shared_ptr<>`.  What do you really think this is going to achieve?  'Better "strong ownership"' when you know somehow / require that the manager can't release the object during the period you're using the raw pointer - doesn't add up....

Comment: I edited the question (added `rationale`) to answer the second part of your post.